# Using calloc function for a test programm

Tags: pointers, printf

I am a beginner in coding and I tried to this this little code were my idea was to set the memory allocation for 20 letter from 26 and after that to increase my memory space with realloc and print those letters again. Unfortunately I can't even complete the first step so maybe could someone help me to fix that.

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char ALPHABET[] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    
    char* alp = &ALPHABET;
    alp = (char*)(calloc(20, sizeof(char)));

    if (alp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Der Speicher konnte nicht reserviert werden! \n"); // Couldn't allocate the memory
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i=0; i<alp; i++);
    {
        printf("Das ist ein Alphabet: %c  ",ALPHABET[i]); 
    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thank you so much

Comment: I am sorry for a poor formatting. I tried to formate it correctly but it kind of didn't really worked but i would try to make it better next time.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, there are lots of things wrong in your program that the compiler will catch.